# how to set uilabel height to 0. or uitbleviewcell height to 0?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, ios9

I have a page like this
[image: all values are in UIlabel]

Now if I got any value `nil` I hide that label

Problem :

But when I hide that label it is showing blank space

[image: showing blank space]

here is mycode::

```
 let dic = finalcarexpense.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    if lastcruisebool == true
    {
        cell.lblcruisecontroll.text = (dic["cruise_control"] as? String)!
    }
    else
    {

        cell.lblcruisecontroll.hidden = true
        cell.placecruisecontrol.hidden = true
    }



    if lastremotebool == true
    {
        cell.lblremotecentrallocking.text = (dic["remote_central_locking"] as? String)!
    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblremotecentrallocking.hidden = true
        cell.placeremotecentrallocking.hidden = true
    }


    if lastacbool == true
    {
        cell.lblairconditioning.text = (dic["air_conditioning"] as? String)!
    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblairconditioning.hidden = true
        cell.placeac.hidden = true
    }


    if lastbluetoothbool == true
    {
        cell.lblbluetooth.text = (dic["bluetooth"] as? String)!
    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblbluetooth.hidden = true
        cell.placebluetooth.hidden = true
    }


    if lastradiocdbool == true
    {
        cell.lblradiocd.text = (dic["radio_cd"] as? String)!
    }
    else
    {

        cell.lblradiocd.hidden = true
        cell.placeradiocd.hidden = true
    }


    if lastpowerbool == true
    {
        cell.lblpowersteering.text = (dic["power_steering"] as? String)!
    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblpowersteering.hidden = true
    }
```

so is there any solution like should i set `UILabel` hieght 0?? or should i do this with using `UITableViewCell`??

Comment: Instead of setting `Height` to 0 you should filter your array that contains the data

Comment: but data is not coming in array@HamzaAnsari

Comment: its comes based on what user select@HamzaAnsari

Comment: Remove that cell from tableview depend on data.

Comment: what is the code for removing cell from uitableview?? @iOSGuru

Comment: are these labels inside one cell?

Comment: if its 2 label and is fixed, i suggess to put each pair to uiview then set that uiview frame with height = 0, its quite easy also

Comment: Did you apply constraints to all label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give uilabel height constraint and can set to 0 at running time. as well you can set it frame to 0 so it will be invisible
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have single cell to hold all rows/items to display. If you have like so then it is very difficult to manage empty space between the labels.

You have to adjust the vertical spacing constraint between the labels, even though you set the value of the label as nil. It is a complex one.

It is better to have the below approach.

1. Clear the UITableView seperator color
2. Each row/cell should **reuse** single prototype cell. 1 cell to all.
3. Use UITableViewDelegate's method

   ```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       If(indexPath.row should be should not be shown){
            return 0;//for hiding the row
       }
       return Default Height Of row;

   }
   ```

   I hope somebody will make use of it in future.

Answer (score 1):

Add height constraint to all labels ,drag Outlet for constraints as follows:
[image]

then if you got nil in response from server set height constraint to 0 as follows:

```
 nsLcHeightForLabel.constant = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to change your architecture works with the table. In fact, you should change the number of cells. You need to store data in the model, it might even be an array and your table should be a display of the data, if the cell is not necessary you remove it from the model and reload the table. For this you need use `Dynamic Prototypes` for cells and this methods to work with it:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourDataModel.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCellController
    return cell
}
```

Read for example this tutorial http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Storyboards_and_Swift_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells  to better understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be make (Use of NSLayoutConstraint's constant property ) IBOutlet connection of Height of all labels and set their height zero. this will remove you spacing.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewHeightConstraint;
```

ex. lblairconditioningCostraintHeight.constant=0

[image]

Check height height constraint for address field. I made IBOutlet for that if if address is big it automatically push all label down and vice-versa.

and set label height ZERO in cellForRowAtIndexPath method if no text in label.hope this will help you.